# How to create a compact Qt4 vBoxLayout

Tags: c++, qt4

I've got a vBoxLayout which contains 3 simple buttons, when I increase the size of the widget containing the layout, the spacing between the buttons increases. I would like to stop this behaviour and keep the buttons in a consistent and compact layout, regardless of the size of the parent widget. This is what I've got so far, but it doesn't change the spacing, any suggestions?, thanks.

```
    button_layout = new QVBoxLayout ;
    button_layout -> setSpacing(0);
    button_layout -> setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
```

Comment: Perhaps the buttons have a fixed height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to add a stretchable spacer to the layout:

```
button_layout = new QVBoxLayout ;
button_layout -> setSpacing(0);
button_layout -> setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
button_layout -> addStretch();
button_layout -> addWidget(button_1);
button_layout -> addWidget(button_2);
button_layout -> addWidget(button_3);
```

This would cause the buttons to always be on the bottom of the containing widget.  Note that the horizontal portion would still stretch if your widget expanded that way; to fix that, you need to either wrap in another (HBox) layout or switch to a grid layout.

Comment: wow, thanks, I had intuitively thought that stretches were actually doing the opposite of what you  describe.